# HTTP 401 error message when I try with private enterprise Github account

Tags: rest, api, url, github, github-enterprise

I am working with python + the requests library + github access to get a hook URL.

When I try to access a hook from my personal public git repo, I get the response smoothly:

import json
import requests
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/josenrihernand/github-personal-repo/hooks", auth=("josenrihernand", token)).json()
print("RESPONSE: ", response) ---> IT WORKS (I get the hook url)

However, if I try with a enterprise / private github account, I get an HTTP 401 error message:

import json
import requests
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
response = requests.get("https://MY_DOMAIN/repos/ENTERPRISE_USER/REPO_PATH/hooks", auth=("ENTERPRISE_USER", token)).json()
print("RESPONSE: ", response) ---> I got a 401 error message.

I am sure that the token is ok.

What could be the root cause of that error ? 
Is the get address properly formed ?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Github entreprise base URL for v3 API is :

```
http(s)://hostname/api/v3/
```

check [Rest v3 API doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/#endpoint-urls)

I guess in your case it would be :

```
https://your.domain/api/v3/repos/USER/REPO/hooks
```